# Why does this variable's value equal '0' and not '42?

Tags: c, pointers

I am just beginning to learn C and it is quite confusing. Specifically, pointers is the thing confusing me. I am starting to get my head around it, but I am confused why this specific thing isn't doing as I thought it would.

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 1000;
int *pA = &num1, *pB = &num2;

pA = pB;
*pA = 42;

printf("%d\n", num1);
printf("%d\n", num2);
```

I am aware that, in terms of the pointers in my code, '*' accesses the value stored at the value that the pointer references. In the case of the code below, 'pA' links to 'num1'.

Without using '*' I am also aware that 'pA = pB' is saying that the variable pointer 'pA' now has the same address as 'pB'. This would imply that 'num1' has the value '1000'. Then the value at the address that 'pA' points to gets changed to '42'. Except that it doesn't; 'num1' prints '0' and 'num2' prints 1000.

Please can someone explain what is going wrong?

Comment: *I am also aware that 'pA = pB' is saying that the variable pointer 'pA' now has the same address as 'pB'. This would imply that 'num1' has the value '1000'.*  - Assigning pointer does not change the location or values of variables.

Comment: *"Except that it doesn't; 'num1' prints '0' and 'num2' prints 1000"* - [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4e7489566cd920f). Are you sure that's the exact code you are compiling?

Answer (score 4):

In this line here

```
pA = pB;
```

You set the value of `pA` (the pointer) to the value of `pB`. So it is now also pointing to `num2` (which is where `pB` was pointing).

Thus when you do this:

```
*pA = 42;
```

It sets `num2` to 42.

> Except that it doesn't; 'num1' prints '0' and 'num2' prints 1000.

[Not when I try it.](https://onlinegdb.com/HyAmfpndS)

Comment: I knew I would come away from this looking stupid. I completely ignored the fact that num2 got changed; if I had noticed, I would have worked out that pA pointed to num2. This is just a simple case of not paying attention. Thanks a lot, man.

Answer (score 0):

> I am also aware that 'pA = pB' is saying that the variable pointer
>   'pA' now has the same address as 'pB'

You are wrong. `pA` and `pB` are two different variables that have their own addresses.

For example insert the following statement

```
printf( "&pA = %p, &pB = %p\n", ( void * )&pA, ( void * )&pB );
```

before and after the statement

```
pA = pB;
```

What is in common is that variables now have the same value that is the address of the variable `num2`. So now the two pointers having the same value point to the variable num2. Using any of these pointers you can change the value of the variable `num2`. The address of the variable `num1` early stored in the variable `pA` is now lost because the value of the pointer pA was overwritten in the statement

```
pA = pB;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pA = pB;  //this is assigning the location in memory that pB is pointing to to pA
```

So pA can no longer change the value of num1 because it isn't pointing to num1 anymore. Now it will change the value of anything pB is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in C are actual physical memory locations that contain values. There are four here: num1, which contains the value 0, num2, which contains the value 1000, pA, which initially contains the memory address of num1, and pB, which initially contains the memory address of num2.

When you assign a variable in C, you copy the content of one variable to another. So `pA = pB` means "copy the value of pB into pA". Since pB contained the memory address of num2, now pA also contains the memory address of num2. The memory locations of num1 and num2 haven't changed--they still contain 0 and 1000. The dereferencing assignment `*pA = 42` says "move the value 42 into the memory location contained in pA". Since pA contains the address of num2, num2 is now 42 (and num1 remains 0).